# Web Support Platform - Video, Docs and Chat / Voice

Tags: cross-platform

Just a question about which platform supports the following .:

I will provide technical advice and guidance to colleagues in the field. I imagine that I via their mobile camera can see what is the "problem", but without that they can see me (á la FaceTime). Then I could then drag / drop documents / videos to their screen on which I can draw / indicate what to pay attention to. Furthermore, I could write messages to them and be able to talk live with them. All communications should be recorded / stored on my machine, but could not be recorded / stored on their devices.
Are there any of you have experience with such a platform?
Looking forward to hearing from you.